# Sending login params to Rails server using Volley

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, android-volley

Link to Rails server. https://afternoon-sea-5654.herokuapp.com.
I want to send a simple JSON POST to attempt to login. I get the following volley errors

**Error**

04-09 14:03:56.156    3002-3031/com.digitalnatives.volleytest E/Volley﹕ [244] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://afternoon-sea-5654.herokuapp.com/sessions/create
04-09 14:03:56.160    3002-3002/com.digitalnatives.volleytest E/Volley﹕ [1] 4.onErrorResponse: Error:

---

I can't tell if it's down to the way I am formatting the request. Here is an example login request using curl manually.

Login -
 curl -X POST -d "user[email]=ywaghmare5203@gmail.com&user[password]=12345678&" https://afternoon-sea-5654.herokuapp.com/sessions/create.json

Request perameter:  email, password,

Response Perameter:

{"id":10,"username":"yogeshwaghmare1","email":"ywaghmare5203@gmail.com","password_hash":"$2a$10$pvLhzJlVz8Hl86O7N/ekiO2wrwNxbfTZlYPtccY4f7vXYNFs1vq6a","password_salt":"$2a$10$pvLhzJlVz8Hl86O7N/ekiO","last_login_time":null,"is_active":null,"contact_number":"123456","created_at":"2015-04-01T19:20:37.552Z","updated_at":"2015-04-01T19:20:37.552Z"}

**JSONObjectRequest code**

```
   public void loginTest() {

   private final String LOGIN = "https://afternoon-sea-5654.herokuapp.com/sessions/create";

// Post params to be sent to the server
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // old test code :  params.put("user[email]=test1@gmail.com&",     "user[password]=12345678&");
          params.put("user[email]", "test1@gmail.com");
          params.put("user[password]", "12345678");


    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(LOGIN, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                        responseText.setText("Worked!");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },

        new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            responseText.setText("Nope");
        }
    });

// add the request object to the queue to be executed
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually in response you are not Getting the JSON data. It is returning a HTML message regarding redirection. Your response is **302**

Response code **500** means its a server sided syntax error. You can test your api through online API testing platform like **Runscope**. It really save our time and confusion when we collaborate with web team and android team.

[Runscope Link](http://www.runscope.com)

Comment: When I create a test on Runscope with
POST https://afternoon-sea-5654.herokuapp.com/sessions/create